# merge/lookup to another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes which I need to merge/lookup values:

df1

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 123 |  |
| 456 |  |
| 789 |  |
| 101 | 0.3 |

df2

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 0.1 |
| 456 | 0.2 |

key = distinct value.
I need to look up df2 based on the Key column.

Expected result

| Key | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 0.1 |
| 456 | 0.2 |
| 789 |  |
| 101 | 0.3 |

I have tried following:

```
merged_df = pd.merge(
left = df1,
right = df2,
on = 'Key',
how = 'outer',
)
```

This creates an additional column 'Value_y' in merged df, while I need to get the data in the original df1 'Value' column.

How could I tweak the code, or perhaps there is another function for this task?
Also currently 'Key' value is 3 combined values (product code and two dates), perhaps it's possible to merge on several columns, instead of creating an additional 'Key' column for merging?

Comment: `merged_df  = df1.merge(df2, on='Key', how='left')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it using [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html?highlight=mask#pandas.DataFrame.mask) and [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html?highlight=map#pandas.Series.map)

map the key in the reference DF, and if value is not null, assign it to value in first DF

```
(df['Value']=df['Value'].mask(  
                             (df['Key'].map(df2.set_index('Key').Value)).notna(),
                              df['Key'].map(df2.set_index('Key').Value)
                             )) 
df
```

OR using [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html?highlight=loc#pandas.DataFrame.loc)

```
df.loc[df['Value'].isna(), 'Value'] = df['Key'].map(df2.set_index('Key').Value)
df
```

```
Key     Value
0   123     0.1
1   456     0.2
2   789     NaN
3   101     0.3
```

Answer (score 3):

Concatenate the two dataframes, then groupby `Key` and call `first` on the DataFrame Groupby object:

```py
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('Key', sort=False).first().reset_index()

   Key  Value
0  123    0.1
1  456    0.2
2  789    NaN
3  101    0.3
```

Comment: Thank you, this does work, but due to a rather large dataframe with not so clean early data, this messes up the df.

Comment: Oh Okay, you probably didn't add a good sample of your data to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='Key', how='left', suffixes=('','x')).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,:-1]
```

Output:

```
   Key  Value
0  123    0.1
1  456    0.2
2  789    NaN
3  101    0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `update`

```
df1.set_index('Key', inplace=True)
df1.update(df2.set_index('Key'))
df1.reset_index()
```